# Synchronizing a block of code

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have a piece of java code that creates a directory in the filesystem if not exisiting.
This application is multithreaded (running with 2 threads), so sometime happens that the check `if(!dir.exists())` returns true for both threads, then when in the inner code i call `dir.mkdirs()` one returns true creating the directory and the other returns false, let me show you the code:

```
public void makePath(){
        File path = new File(Main.getPath());
            synchronized (this) {
                if (!path.exists()) {//return true on both treads
                    if (path.mkdirs()) {//return true only on one thread
                        logger.warn("Path was not existing, just created one");
                    } else {//returns false only on one thread
                        logger.warn("Problems while creating pth");
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

My initial version had no synchronized block, i thought that that would solve the issue but it does not.
When i run with a single thread everything goes fine, with a single thread the `!path.exists()` returns true only once.

Comment: Could you let me know how did you call this method?

Comment: Hi, its a piece of code within a method in a class implementing Callable, an executor service then calls this object in a pool of max 2 threads.

Comment: If you are synchronized on `this` (the current instance of whatever class defines the method), then that doesn't prevent another instance running the same block at the same time. You need to sync on the same object.

Comment: @JBoy are you creating two or more instances of your callable? Or you have created only one instance of your callable and passed that instance to executor service?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia yes, more instaces put in a thread pool

Comment: issue fixed, pls see my answer, of course if you have better suggestion i am open for refactoring

Answer (score 3):

It is because you Synchronizing in inner class.

```
synchronized (this)
```

It must not be `this`, it could be some other object out side of this method, like it can be a field

You can change the code like this:

```
synchronized (Foo.class)
```

Comment: well its not an inner class, but i guess i know what you mean

Comment: @JBoy Edited the answer, you can try it

Comment: How about creating a method in another class "a static util" that checks/creates files and directories, and make that method synchronized? so the actual class running the thread will no longer handle creation/checking of files but will delegate it to this method

Comment: The better way to do this is the start of application, because synchronization will affect the performance, try to don't use synchronization if is possible...

Answer (score 2):

If you are synchronized on `this` (the current instance of whatever class defines the method), then that doesn't prevent another instance running the same block at the same time, because it will be synchronizing on itself. You need to sync on the same object.

E.g.

```
private static Object syncKey = new Object();
public void makePath() {
    synchronized (syncKey) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So i should delegate the creation/checking of the file to a different method on another class "lets say an Util" and define THAT new method as synchronized?

Comment: Only if you think it makes your code more readable or maintainable. If you are syncing on an instance of a utility class, you still have to make sure you are syncing both threads on the same instance of that class. Or sync on the class itself.

Comment: how about a static method? see my answer above, this way the util wont need to be synced, only the method

Comment: Putting `synchronized` on a static method is just the same as putting a `synchronized (MyClass.class)` block inside the method. You're not gaining or losing anything by using a synchronized method instead of a sync block.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it delegating the function to create files or check for their existence to a Util. the callable instance then calls this method instead of creating the files by itself

```
    /**
 * Create a directory and its sub directories in a synchronized way
 * 
 * @param file
 * @return
 */
public static synchronized boolean createDirsIfNecessary(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```